# Why are images from newly created folder not showing my custom gallery

Tags: android, gallery, image-gallery

If I create a folder programmatically and store some images in that folder then my custom gallery shows only previous folders until I rename this folder. once I rename or edit this folder from File Manager then all the images will show.
Here is my code

```
 ArrayList<imageFolder> picFolders = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> picPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        Uri allImagesuri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA , MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID};
        Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(allImagesuri, projection, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            do{
                imageFolder folds = new imageFolder();
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String folder = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME));
                String datapath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));

                //String folderpaths =  datapath.replace(name,"");
                String folderpaths = datapath.substring(0, datapath.lastIndexOf(folder+"/"));
                folderpaths = folderpaths+folder+"/";
                if (!picPaths.contains(folderpaths)) {
                    picPaths.add(folderpaths);

                    folds.setPath(folderpaths);
                    folds.setFolderName(folder);
                    folds.setFirstPic(datapath);//if the folder has only one picture this line helps to set it as first so as to avoid blank image in itemview
                    folds.addpics();
                    picFolders.add(folds);
                }else{
                    for(int i = 0;i<picFolders.size();i++){
                        if(picFolders.get(i).getPath().equals(folderpaths)){
                            picFolders.get(i).setFirstPic(datapath);
                            picFolders.get(i).addpics();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: That is code to list files. To see what MediaStore contains. Its irrelevant at this moment. Remove it. Post your code where you create folder and files. You did not even tell in which folder you created all.

Comment: I am use this code for folder creation File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(),
                "My Folder/"+ System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

Comment: That code does not create a folder. Nor a file.

Answer (score 0):

For adding images to your gallery, you have to use ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
requireContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

For API level 29 and above, you have to use `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile` method

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(requireContext(),
                    new String[]{imageFile.toString()},
                    null,
                    null);
```